# Non-recursive binary string permutation generator

Tags: c++

So I'm working on a problem where I need to generate permutations of binary strings that are not only a specific length, but also contain a specific number of ones and zeros. I have an algorithm that does this, however it is a recursive one and I am dealing with 64 bit, unsigned integers so there is a potential for them to be too large for the function to handle. Was hoping someone could help me out or suggest another algorithm that I should take a look at. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using std::next_permutation?

Comment: What is the maximum length for the string?

Comment: The max length would be 64 chars

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to lean on standard library with this task. You can use the `std::next_permutation` function which will provide you all possible permutations. Please take a look at this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

template <class T>
void print(const T& array)
{
    std::cout << "{ ";
    for(bool i : array) { std::cout << i << " "; }
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<bool, 5> data = { false, false, true, true, true };

    print(data);

    while(std::next_permutation(std::begin(data), std::end(data)))
    {
            print(data);
    }
}
```

And this would result with something like this:

```
{ 0 0 1 1 1 }
{ 0 1 0 1 1 }
{ 0 1 1 0 1 }
{ 0 1 1 1 0 }
{ 1 0 0 1 1 }
{ 1 0 1 0 1 }
{ 1 0 1 1 0 }
{ 1 1 0 0 1 }
{ 1 1 0 1 0 }
{ 1 1 1 0 0 }
```

Edit:

If you want to be able to pick number of ones and zeroes in runtime and you need the permutation to be in form of a string you can prepare first permutation as `std::string` and use `std::next_permutation` on it. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::string constructFirstPermutation(size_t numberOfZeros, size_t numberOfOnes)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(numberOfZeros + numberOfOnes);
    result.append(numberOfZeros, '0');
    result.append(numberOfOnes, '1');

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string data = constructFirstPermutation(5,10);

    std::cout << data << std::endl;

    while(std::next_permutation(std::begin(data), std::end(data)))
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `vector<bool>` is worth avoiding - it's sadly not what you might expect. `deque<bool>` or `vector<char>` are less likely to cause grief.

Comment: @AlanStokes Or simply `bool[n]` if possible at all.

Comment: @AlanStokes I have changes `vector<bool>` to `array<bool>`. Wasn't aware of `vector<bool>` problems, thanks

Comment: Is there any way for me to set the { false, false, true, true, true } part dynamically? Sorry, but I'm pretty new to C++.

Comment: @Phil_B Plenty of ways, i.e. you can use the `std::string` to do the job, I have altered my answer with the example

Answer (score 0):

If you do the recursion right, you can handle binary sequences of length 64 and much more.

In the following algorithm the depth of the recursion is bounded by the length of the sequence (which is 64 in your case), and in each level of recursion we only put a few bytes on the stack. Instead of storing all of the results, we simply output a sequence whenever it is ready, so we don't accumulate lots of sequences in memory. Notice how the `s` variable is being passed down through the recursion.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void create_all_binary_subsequence(std::string& s, int offset, int num_of_ones, std::function<void(const std::string& s)> callback)
{
    if (num_of_ones == 0)
        callback(s);
    else {
        for (int i = offset; i <= (int)s.size() - num_of_ones; ++i) {
            s[i] = '1';
            create_all_binary_subsequence(s, i + 1, num_of_ones - 1, callback);
            s[i] = '0';
        }
    }
}

void create_all_binary_sequences(int num_of_ones, int length, std::function<void(const std::string& s)> callback) {
    std::string s(length, '0');
    create_all_binary_subsequence(s, 0, num_of_ones, callback);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    create_all_binary_sequences(3, 5, [](const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << s.c_str() << "\n";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
11100
11010
11001
10110
10101
10011
01110
01101
01011
00111
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. However I need to get the generated permutations as a whole string. Is there any way for me to do that using this existing code? I tried playing around with the cast you have on seq[i], and I also tried setting that char array to a string, but neither of those worked.

Comment: Ok. I modified the algorithm to use std::string instead of char arrays. It is now shorter and faster